# Incorrect page title "Answers By New Users"

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, top-users

The page `https://stackoverflow.com/tags/`*`tag`*`/new` contains the title "Answers By New Users" ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/new))

[image: Image of the Page Title]
It rather should be new Answers or similar. After all, the page also shows answers by old users like me.

Comment: curious on the downvote. why?

Comment: Maybe someone misunderstood "old users"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed, with you in the next build.